# Debezium from snowflake and kafka

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-redshift, debezium

> We want to capture CDC from snowflake and Redshift and publish to kafka broker. Is it possible with Debezium

Comment: Not sure about Debezium but you could certainly build something to 
PUSH from snowflake using a Task to Unload to a bucket for Kafka to reference
PULL from Snowflake's SQL API